# object.keys converted arrays are different from another arrays?

Tags: arrays, object

When I use `Object.keys` to convert Object to Array, and then create another Array that looks the same, they have different results. Could you explain please, how does `keys.forEach()` know values of **person** keys while `test.forEach()` shows them as "undefined":

```
const person = {
    key1: 'value1',
    key2: 'value2',
    key3: 'value3'
}

const keys = Object.keys(person)

const test = ['1', '2', '3']

keys.forEach(key => {
    console.log(key)
    console.log(person[key])
})

test.forEach(some => {
    console.log(some)
    console.log(person[some])
})

// key1
// value1
// key2
// value2
// key3
// value3
// 1
// undefined
// 2
// undefined
// 3
// undefined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to test array have the values `['1', '2', '3']` instead of `['key1', 'key2', 'key3']`

What you are seeing in the `undefined` output is `person['1']`, etc, which in fact is not defined

Answer (score 0):

The forEach() method executes a provided function once for each array element.

```
var obj = {"1":5,"2":7,"3":0,"4":0,"5":0,"6":0,"7":0,"8":0,"9":0,"10":0,"11":0,"12":0}



  var result = Object.keys(obj).map(function(key) {
      return [Number(key), obj[key]];
    });
    
    console.log(result);
```